# Return Vector of Boxed objects

Tags: rust

I am trying to return a vector of dynamic objects, so I'm wrapping each element in a `Box`. This works when I initialise a vector and immediately return it, but it does not work if I create a temporary variable.

I really need the second method, because I would like to do some operations before actually returning the vector.

Here's a minimal reproducable example:

```
trait Dynamic {
    fn foo(&self);
} 

struct Concrete {
    bar: i32
}

impl Concrete {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar: value
        }
    }
}

impl Dynamic for Concrete {
    fn foo(&self) {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn generate() -> Vec<Box<dyn Dynamic>> {
    // this works
    vec![
        Box::new(Concrete::new(1)),
        Box::new(Concrete::new(3))
    ]

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // this does not work with the error: expected `Vec<Box<(dyn Dynamic + 'static)>>`
    let temp = vec![
        Box::new(Concrete::new(1)),
        Box::new(Concrete::new(3))
    ];

    temp
}

fn main() {
    let result = generate();
    
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I'm not sure where the `'static` is coming from. I don't want the elements in the vector to be `static` either, because in the future, I need to read these values from a file or other external provider so they won't be `static`.

Comment: The `'static` comes from [the lifetime elision rules for trait objects lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes). Having the `'static` lifetime just means that the type does not contain any references with shorter lifetimes. Owned types are always `'static`. This doesn't mean they necessarily live for the whole duration of the program execution – just that they don't contain any references that could ever become invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just annotate your temp variable with the proper type:

```rust
let temp: Vec<Box<dyn Dynamic>> = vec![
    Box::new(Concrete::new(1)),
    Box::new(Concrete::new(3))
];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca4b7c405bd8e00087b0f91ac59c497b)

Comment: Alternatively, annotate the first item with ` as Box<dyn Dynamic>`.

Comment: Wow, it was this simple? It looks like I trusted the Rust typing inference system too much.

Comment: Well, here it's just that Rust refuses to do both inference _and_ coercion (from `Box<Concrete>` to `Box<dyn Dynamic>`) at the same time, so that you don't have any coercion slipping in unexpectedly. The type can be inferred, but it deliberately isn't.